# Multiply & Divide Non-type and int in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

So I am writing a simple program that calculates your BMI. I am running into an issue when it is time to calculate the BMI by taking the returned values of weight and height (it acts as if there is no value being returned). This code use to work when I had all modules in one function, since I have divided all functions into separate modules I have run into this issue.

```
>     Error:
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "C:/OneDrive/Documents/3.py", line 43, in <module>
>         bmi = calcBMI(weight, height)
>       File "C:/OneDrive/Documents/3.py", line 17, in calcBMI
>         bmi = float(weight * 703 / (height * height))
>     TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Here's my code:

> ```
> ##########
> # Functions
> ##########
> def getweight():
>     weight = float(input('Enter your weight in LBs: '))
>     if weight <= 0 or weight > 1000:
>         print('Weight cannot be less than 0 or greater than 700')
>         return weight
>
> def getheight():
>     height = float(input('Enter your height in inches: '))
>     if height <= 0:
>         print('Height cannot be less than 0')
>         return height
>
> def calcBMI(weight, height):
>     bmi = float(weight * 703 / (height * height))
>     return bmi
>
> def printData(name, bmi):
>     print(name)
>     print('Your BMI is %.2f' % bmi)
>     if bmi >= 18.5 and bmi <= 24.9:
>         print('Your BMI is normal')
>     elif bmi <= 18.5:
>         print('Your BMI is underweight')
>     elif bmi >= 25 and bmi <= 29.9:
>         print('Your BMI is overweight')
>     elif bmi >= 30:
>         print('**Your BMI is obese**')
>
> #####################
> # Beginning of program
> #####################
> print("Welcome to the Body Mass Index Calculator")
>
> name = input('Enter your name or 0 to quit: ')
>
> # beginning of loop
> while name != "0":
>     height = getheight()
>     weight = getweight()
>     bmi = calcBMI(weight, height)
>     printData(name, weight, height, bmi)
>     name = input('Enter another name or 0 to quit: ')
>
> print("Exiting program...")
> ```

Answer (score 6):

For a start, you are only returning height if it is less than 0. You would want to remove the `return` statement from within the `if` block.

You probably also want to create some logic to deal with an incorrect height being entered, such as raising an exception, or returning the user to the prompt.

```
def getweight():
    weight = float(input('Enter your weight in LBs: '))
    if weight <= 0 or weight > 1000:
        print('Weight cannot be less than 0 or greater than 700')
        #Some code here to deal with a weight less than 0
    return weight

def getheight():
    height = float(input('Enter your height in inches: '))
    if height <= 0:
        print('Height cannot be less than 0')
        #Some code here to deal with a height less than 0
    return height
```

One way of dealing with incorrect weights would be:

```
def getweight():
    while True:
        weight = float(input('Enter your weight in LBs: '))
        if weight <= 0 or weight > 1000:
            print('Weight cannot be less than 0 or greater than 700')
        else:
            return weight
```

You may want to limit this to a certain number of iterations - up to you.

Comment: Even better: adding a loop (to each).

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realize how simple the mistake was. I have removed the if blocks from both modules and the code works as it should.

Answer (score 2):

Neither `getheight` nor `getweight` necessarily returns a number (i.e. when the `if` fails); in such cases, it returns `None`.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Now in cases where the 'if' is not failing, why would it not return a value? From what I understand after digging around, I am receiving a type error because my nontype may not have a value assigned to it when it is being called

Comment: How do you know such cases are occurring?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure if that was the case. I was assuming it was not assigning my inputted values because it was returned as a type error. I'm still learning so I am soaking all this information. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Don't assume; test.